# SP2013. Allowing visitors to manage permissions for lists and folders

Tags: 2013, permissions, inheritance

Is there a way for visitors to Sharepoint site to have the ability to manage permissions (ie, break inheritance, and grant permissions to others) for lists and folders. But not the site-wide permissions.

I am using Sharepoint 2013.

Answer (score 0):

You break the permission at List level by stop inheritance from Permission at list setting.And remove all user and grant permission to Visitor group.

Note-Make sure of your business requirement before breaking permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the visitors are in a SharePoint group and have read access to the site. Use admin account to manage the list permission, break the inheritance, add the visitors group with Full Control. Then the visitors can manage the permissions and content of the list.
If there are more than one list to allow visitors to manage permission, repeat the same procedure for each list.